# Add a caption to an image with docx4j

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

i would like to link a caption to an image using docx4j.

```
BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart;
imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(wordMLPackage, bytes);
Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline(filenameHint, altText, id1, id2, false);

ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
P imageParagraph = factory.createP();
R run = factory.createR();
imageParagraph.getContent().add(run);
Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
run.getContent().add(drawing);
drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);
```

I have seen something link CTCaption but i don't know how to link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word adds the caption as a sibling w:p following the one containing the image, using w:fldSimple for the numbering:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:drawing>
      <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="27B5888C" wp14:editId="054E2550">
        <wp:extent cx="6010910" cy="2385060"/>
        <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="8890" b="0"/>
        <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="Graphical user interface, text&#xA;&#xA;Description automatically generated"/>
        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
          <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
          <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
              <pic:nvPicPr>
                <pic:cNvPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="Graphical user interface, text&#xA;&#xA;Description automatically generated"/>
                <pic:cNvPicPr/>
              </pic:nvPicPr>
              <pic:blipFill>
                <a:blip r:embed="rId4"/>
                <a:stretch>
                  <a:fillRect/>
                </a:stretch>
              </pic:blipFill>
              <pic:spPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                  <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                  <a:ext cx="6010910" cy="2385060"/>
                </a:xfrm>
                <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                  <a:avLst/>
                </a:prstGeom>
              </pic:spPr>
            </pic:pic>
          </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
      </wp:inline>
    </w:drawing>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Caption"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">Figure </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:fldSimple w:instr=" SEQ Figure \* ARABIC ">
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:noProof/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>1</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:fldSimple>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>YOUR CAPTION HERE</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Indicative Java code for that w:p

```
    // Create object for p
    P p4 = wmlObjectFactory.createP(); 
    body.getContent().add( p4); 
        // Create object for r
        R r4 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p4.getContent().add( r4); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text3 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped3 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text3); 
            r4.getContent().add( textWrapped3); 
                text3.setValue( "Figure "); 
                text3.setSpace( "preserve"); 
        // Create object for r
        R r5 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p4.getContent().add( r5); 
            // Create object for fldChar (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            FldChar fldchar = wmlObjectFactory.createFldChar(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.FldChar> fldcharWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createRFldChar(fldchar); 
            r5.getContent().add( fldcharWrapped); 
                fldchar.setFldCharType(org.docx4j.wml.STFldCharType.BEGIN);
        // Create object for r
        R r6 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p4.getContent().add( r6); 
            // Create object for instrText (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text4 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped4 = wmlObjectFactory.createRInstrText(text4); 
            r6.getContent().add( textWrapped4); 
                text4.setValue( " SEQ Figure \\* ARABIC "); 
                text4.setSpace( "preserve"); 
        // Create object for r
        R r7 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p4.getContent().add( r7); 
            // Create object for fldChar (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            FldChar fldchar2 = wmlObjectFactory.createFldChar(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.FldChar> fldcharWrapped2 = wmlObjectFactory.createRFldChar(fldchar2); 
            r7.getContent().add( fldcharWrapped2); 
                fldchar2.setFldCharType(org.docx4j.wml.STFldCharType.SEPARATE);
        // Create object for r
        R r8 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p4.getContent().add( r8); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text5 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped5 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text5); 
            r8.getContent().add( textWrapped5); 
                text5.setValue( "1"); 
            // Create object for rPr
            RPr rpr3 = wmlObjectFactory.createRPr(); 
            r8.setRPr(rpr3); 
                // Create object for noProof
                BooleanDefaultTrue booleandefaulttrue3 = wmlObjectFactory.createBooleanDefaultTrue(); 
                rpr3.setNoProof(booleandefaulttrue3); 
        // Create object for r
        R r9 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p4.getContent().add( r9); 
            // Create object for fldChar (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            FldChar fldchar3 = wmlObjectFactory.createFldChar(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.FldChar> fldcharWrapped3 = wmlObjectFactory.createRFldChar(fldchar3); 
            r9.getContent().add( fldcharWrapped3); 
                fldchar3.setFldCharType(org.docx4j.wml.STFldCharType.END);
            // Create object for rPr
            RPr rpr4 = wmlObjectFactory.createRPr(); 
            r9.setRPr(rpr4); 
                // Create object for noProof
                BooleanDefaultTrue booleandefaulttrue4 = wmlObjectFactory.createBooleanDefaultTrue(); 
                rpr4.setNoProof(booleandefaulttrue4); 
        // Create object for r
        R r10 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p4.getContent().add( r10); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text6 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped6 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text6); 
            r10.getContent().add( textWrapped6); 
                text6.setValue( "YOUR CAPTION HERE"); 
        // Create object for pPr
        PPr ppr2 = wmlObjectFactory.createPPr(); 
        p4.setPPr(ppr2); 
            // Create object for pStyle
            PPrBase.PStyle pprbasepstyle = wmlObjectFactory.createPPrBasePStyle(); 
            ppr2.setPStyle(pprbasepstyle); 
                pprbasepstyle.setVal( "Caption");
```

Answer (score -1):

How does the table number can be dynamic, if the above code is created as a re-usable method and called for each table that got created how does the text5.setValue() can be a sequence

Comment: seems more like a comment as you're asking for more clarification on the question. please remove answer and ask as comment and answer the question with solution with more detailed answer for future reference even if accepted answer exists. accepted answer is not always the clear answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to add comment to someone else answers, so added as an answer